# How do sophisticated generalized frontrunner bots work?

Tags: solidity, txpool, frontrunning, flashbots

By sophisticated generalized frontrunner bots, I mean the bots that execute a pending mempool transaction and copy profitable internal transactions generated by its execution trace, as mentioned in the famous [dark forest article](https://www.paradigm.xyz/2020/08/ethereum-is-a-dark-forest/).

How does that even work? I'm very interested in the implementation details.

Comment: Whoever designs a profitable frontrunner bot will want to keep it a secret. Otherwise, it will have more competition and become not profitable.